# C++ templates: do something inside a function, depending on the template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Please take a look into the member function `virtual std::future<void> DoInvoke ()` of the class `EventMemberImpl`:

```
#include <future>
#include <functional>

class EventImpl
{
public:
  virtual ~EventImpl () = default;
  std::future<void> Invoke () { return DoInvoke (); }
private:
  virtual std::future<void> DoInvoke () = 0;
};

template <typename... Ts>
EventImpl * MakeEvent (Ts&&... args)
{
  class EventMemberImpl : public EventImpl
  {
public:
    EventMemberImpl (Ts&&... args)
      : m_function (std::bind (std::forward<Ts> (args)...))
    {
    }
protected:
    virtual ~EventMemberImpl ()
    {
    }
private:
    virtual std::future<void> DoInvoke ()
    {
      // MakeEvent has been called with
      // a Callable which does not return a future
      m_function ();
      return std::future<void> ();
      // OR
      // MakeEvent has been called with a
      // Callable which returns a future:
      return m_function();
    }
     // In case is any function...  :
    std::function<void ()> m_function;

    // OR
    // ... except when it returns a future:
    std::function<std::future<void> ()> m_function;
  };
  return new EventMemberImpl (std::forward<Ts> (args)...);
}

int foo() { return 5; }
std::future<int> baz () { return std::future<int> (); }

int main ()
{

  EventImpl *event1 = MakeEvent(std::forward<decltype (&foo)> (&foo));
  EventImpl *event2 = MakeEvent(std::forward<decltype (&baz)> (&baz));

  return 0;
}
```

What I would like to do is that, when someone calls MakeEvent with a function (any callable) as a parameter that returns void (or almost anything else) then the body should behave exactly as I wrote it. On the other hand, when the MakeEvent function is called with a function as a parameter which returns a std::future, then it should do different things.

Comment: Is C++14 allowed or you're stuck to C++11?

Comment: Is allowed, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mix of `std::conditional` and function overloading.

Let us define an alias to the return type of the function:

```
using result = decltype(std::bind(std::declval<Ts>()...)());
```

Then, we can make another alias to our conditions:

```
template<typename T>
using is_future = std::is_convertible<T, std::future<void>>;
```

Then, with that condition, we can declare our member:

```
std::conditional_t<is_future<result>::value,
    std::function<std::future<void>>,
    std::function<void()>
> m_function;
```

Then, we can overload a function to conditionally select which expression is needed. In C++17, only a constexpr if it's needed:

```
virtual std::future<void> DoInvoke () {
    if constexpr (!is_future<result>::value) {
        m_function ();
        return std::future<void>();
    } else {
        return m_function();
    }
}
```

In contrast with C++14, you need to overload the function, and use sfinae:

```
template<typename F, std::enable_if_t<is_future<std::result_of_t<F()>>::value>* = nullptr>
auto DoInvokeSelect(F& function) -> std::future<void> {
    return function();
}

template<typename F, std::enable_if_t<!is_future<std::result_of_t<F()>>::value>* = nullptr>
auto DoInvokeSelect(F& function) -> std::future<void> {
    function();
    return std::future<void>();
}

virtual std::future<void> DoInvoke () {
    return DoInvokeSelect(m_function);
}
```

The enable_if will select either functions if the result is a future or not.

Comment: Wow, this opened my mind a lot. Only one comment (maybe it's a wrong one): `DoInvokeSelect(F& function) -> std::future<void()>` should be `DoInvokeSelect(F& function) -> std::future<void>`, right?

Comment: @kronat yes you are right, I'll edit my answer right away.